# mysql TEXT inserts empty strings instead of null

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a mysql table with a `TEXT` column defined as such in the table creation.

`foo` TEXT

It's simply a field called `foo` that is a TEXT value. TEXT is `DEFAULT NULL` by default and so I didn't need to explicitly specify the constraint. In attempting to insert foos with empty string '' into the table - I don't get any rows with `foo` as `Null` - instead they're all empty string ''. I'm using the node mysql lib to do the insert.

I thought empty string would've gotten inserted as NULL, but that is not the case. Any ideas? I suppose I can resolve this on the JS end by doing something like `delete foo if !foo`. But I'd rather not. Thanks!

Comment: An empty string is absolutely not the same as an explicit `NULL` value (in any RDBMS that comes to my mind) - can you provide an authoritative source for your claim that an "*empty string would've gotten inserted as NULL*"? From [this relevant DBA.StackExchange answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59/when-to-use-null-and-when-to-use-an-empty-string/75#75): "`NULL` [indicates an explicit] absence of value (i.e. there is *no value*), while empty string [indicates explicitly] there is a *string value* of zero length."

Comment: empty string is a string value, Null is the absence of the value, however, to set the default value, don't pass a value for this column

Comment: *I suppose I can resolve this on the JS end by doing something like `delete foo if !foo`* This query will NOT delete rows with NULLs. But it will delete all NOT NULL rows. After syntax correction, of course.

Comment: @esqew FWIW, Oracle database treats `''` and NULL as equivalent. This is not standard SQL, but they have done it for decades.

Comment: @BillKarwin My limited experience with Oracle is showing! Thanks for the fact-check.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I assumed '' would get inserted as Null. Thanks for clarifying @esqew